# How to reverse a mathematical expression saved as a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Suppose a string

```
var click="2+5-7%8"
```

is to be reversed to become

```
"8%7-5+2"
```

How to do it in Javascript? I am trying to complete the Free Code Camp Calculator Zipline.

Comment: use "2+5-7%8".split('').reverse().join('');

Comment: How do you do if it is `"-2+5-7%8"` is to be `"8%7-5+2-"` which seems invalid to me...

Comment: We're not going to show you how to do it, the whole point of a code camp is to try to figure it out yourself. Make an attempt, and if you can't get it working post your code. Then we'll show you where you went wrong and help you fix it, and you'll actually learn somethingl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function r(s) {
  var txt = "";
  for(var i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    txt += s[i];
  }
  return txt;
}

var mathex = "2+5-7%8";

alert(r(mathex));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple reverse and join solution.

```
str.split("").reverse().join("");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript String Reverse</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
    function strReverse(str){
        return str.split('').reverse().join('');
    }

    var click = "2+5-7%8";
    var revClick = strReverse(click);
    document.write("click = " + click + "<br>");
    document.write("revClick = " + revClick + "<br>");

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/07/reversing-a-string-in-javascript-3-different-ways/) article describes three different ways:
* Array.reverse
* Decrementing while-loop
* Recursion

Recursion seems a better approach. That's why I will list it here:

```
function reverseString(str) {
    return (str === '') ? '' : reverseString(str.substr(1)) + str.charAt(0);
}
reverseString('dwayne');
```

Hope it helps